# Cucumber.js debugging in IntelliJ

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, bdd, cucumberjs

IntelliJ has a plugin for Cucumber.js. This suppose to enable running and debugging inside the IDE. The run configuration for cucumber.js works, but the debug mode is deactivated (Debug button can not be clicked). Does anybody else has the same problem and managed to solve it? Debugging is very essential to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using the cucumber.js plugin, I used the run/debug configuration of node.js.

I just set the run config of the node.js plugin like that ->
JavaScript file: node_modules/.bin/cucumber.js (any path to the cucumber.js file)

Comment: For anyone else trying this, the above did not work for me, possibly because I'm running on Windows. Instead, use the cucumber.js inside the cucumber module: node_modules\cucumber\bin\cucumber.js

Comment: you could also add a particular feature file with "Application parameters" option like this 

features/simple_math.feature

Answer (score 0):

I have added support it via cucumberjs grunt plugin. Hope thats what your are looking for. Here, https://github.com/mavdi/grunt-cucumberjs#optionsdebugger