# Can't debug using cucumber.js plugin in IntelliJ

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, bdd, cucumberjs

I've set up Cucumber.js plugin according to https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/run-debug-configuration-cucumber-js.html

It is title Run/Debug. Run part works. Debug - doesn't. The button is just disabled. Is that right?

I saw this [Cucumber.js debugging in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30640253/cucumber-js-debugging-in-intellij), but I'd want to use the original plugin.